# What could cause a Trane furnace to not start heating?

Tags: heating, furnace

I have a newer (2007?) Trane XL90 (model: tdx2b080a9422aa)forced air gas furnace. The problem I am having is the burner and fan will not start. The thermostat is set at 67 degrees and shows it is calling for heat but no heat. Noticed it started coming on and off intermittently over the last few days. I took a multimeter to the ignitor and its not reading ohms. Have not checked the flame sensor yet. Should I? Also the fan is on on the thermostat, however it will not start on the furnace. Is this a startup sequence issue? the fan should start first I believe. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What error code are you getting? (blinking lights; what's the pattern and number of the flashes?) There should be a switch for the power; turn it off. If not you may need to cycle the breaker to *actually* reset it. FIRST make note of any error codes.

Comment: Four red flashes. Indicates open temp limit switch.

Comment: Sounds like the plenum overheat sensor.

Comment: Do you live with this person, lol... http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/51891/split-pack-heating-air-unit

Comment: I could not find any documentation on your equipment. Could you please include the schematic for the furnace, which you should be able to find in the documentation or on the inside of the service panel?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue... I did the filter change, checked all the thermoswitches then it worked for a few hours then no heat LED flashing 4 times. Then I measured the voltage from the 24V transformer and the voltage would vary from 11V to 19V max. Replace transformer and furnace is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Yours may be different, but generally [high temp limit switches](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_kw=trane%20limit%20switch) look like this:

[image]

Order the correct replacement online (if you can figure out the right one to get and have verified it has failed by testing for broken continuity) or take it to your local appliance parts supplier. Bring the model number of your unit with.

---

"well 4 blinks is an open limit or **roll out**" -[Matthew](http://www.justanswer.com/hvac/4ighx-trane-95xv-red-light-flashing-times.html)

What else is on the same wire? (test the other parts of the safety chain)

**[Roll out switch](http://www.mobilehomerepair.com/NordyneGas.php)**:

[image]

---

After replacing a faulty ignitor, the elusive culprit for the OP was **old batteries in the thermostat**.

"I replaced the batteries in the thermostat, even though it wasn't calling for new batteries and now it works".

Comment: Replace that along with the ignitor? Am I able to test resistance on the limit switch?

Comment: @Nick A limit switch is a switch, it's either open or closed. You can test it using the continuity or ohm setting on you multimeter. If the switch is closed, you'll get a reading between the two terminals. If the switch is open, you won't get a reading or you'll measure infinite ohms. The high limit should only be open if the furnace is over heated. If it's open when the furnace is cold, it's bad and needs to be replaced.

Comment: Thanks tester101. So would that relate to the fan not starting when the thermostat kicks on?

Comment: Ok I removed the limit switch. got a ohm reading of infinity. Going to replace that as well as the ignitor. Is it common for them to both be bad at the same time? In regards to the blower fan, all breakers are good. Filters were clean however one had gotten dislodged at some point since I replaced them last month and left a decent sized gap. Would this cause these issues?

Comment: OK back from the local HVAC dealer. Took my ignitor and limit switch. Ignitor was bad and replaced. Limit switch was good. Come back home to put everything back together and its still the sam . No blower fan. And its still flashing 4 red lights. Any ideas? @tester101

Comment: @Nick Did you pop the 3 amp fuse on the board (if you were messing with it with the power on it probably tripped).

Comment: @nick cycle the breaker again to reset the lock-out.

Comment: @nick "one of the filters..." do you have 2 filters in parallel (OK) or in series (not OK)?

Comment: If you flip the switch at the thermostat to FAN (or ON not AUTO),  does the blower come on?

Comment: Filters are in a 'v' position

Comment: Blower does not come on after thermostat is switched.

Comment: @nick That's fine, too. Unit status?

Comment: @nick Did you check the roll-out sensors (They should read ~0 ohms), the little fuse, and power cycle the unit?

Comment: Have not tried the roll out switch. At work now will continue in the A.M.

Comment: If the blower does not come on when the thermostat is set to the `FAN` (or `ON`) position, there's possibly a problem with the control board. I can't find the schematic for this model online, so I can't confirm this but the blower should turn on despite an open limit. The problem could also be a bad thermostat. Have you tried bypassing the thermostat?

Comment: There should be no ignition sequence for simply turning on the blower in `FAN` mode, it should simply activate the blower relay. If you can't even get that to work, the problem is likely "before" the limits. This would point to the thermostat, control board, power source, or possibly even the blower motor itself.

Comment: Agreed, at this point I'd be hot-wiring the blower to test it. A lockout *could* prevent the unit from doing anything.

Comment: Ok guys. Furnace is fixed. As simple as it sounds, I was told to replace the batteries in the thermostat even if it isnt calling for new batteries. Turned on the fan only and then turned heat on and voila! I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

My Trane XR90 gas furnace was not producing heat.  The red diagnostic light was blinking 4 times, which means "Open High Temperature Limit Device".

I did some analysis and found that I have two flexible condensate hoses that drain into two 3/4 PVC pipes.  These PVC pipes meet at a Y junction and drain into one PVC pipe that leads to the exterior.  The plumbers clay around one of the flexible hoses was old and crumbling, allowing air to enter. This was creating a backdraft, which prevented condensate from draining and causing a sensor to trip the unit.  As soon as I removed the old, crumbling clay and replaced it with new, pliable clay, the unit starting heating again.  Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

It has been my experience that these units are very air filter sensitive, i.e. if dirty or the wrong filter merv rating is used they will go into a limited mode - - - try changing the filter to a Merv 8 and see if it fires up normally .....